# Проверка версии браузера

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как через jQuery проверить браузер, которого нет среди заранее заготовленных? Например Maxthon.

Comment: Зачем проверить браузер? В болшинстве случаев лучше использовать feature detection.

Answer (score 3):

Каждый браузер имеет строку `navigator.userAgent`, например, в моей версии Хрома:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
```

`navigator.userAgent` браузера Maxthon, может быть такое:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Maxthon/3.0.8.2 Safari/533.1"
```

[Можно найти список таких строков в UserAgentString.com](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

Если хотите проверить, если браузер Maxthon, то можно так:

```
navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf("MAXTHON") !== -1
```

Хочу предупреждать, что не всегда легко угадать браузер от `navigator.userAgent`, потому что браузеры обычно создают строку `userAgent` ради совместимости сайтов. Именно поэтому `Mozilla/5.0` уже не имеет отношение с браузерами Mozilla. Оно там, потому что давно много сайтов только поддерживали Netscape.

Answer (score 2):

Через объект navigator в целом, или через navigator.userAgent в частности

например

```
      var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      var isMaxthon = ua.indexOf("maxthon") > -1;//если в строке встречается слово "maxthon" ( toLowerCase() был нужен, чтобы не морочится с заглавными и строчными буквами, иначе  "Maxthon" != "maxthon" )
      var isMSIE = ua.indexOf("msie") > -1;//А это - для ie
      [...]//и т.д. - можно хоть все загнать
      //и длее, где нужно проверить максона это или нет
      if(isMaxthon){[...]}
```

это просто как пример - можно и упростить

версию же можно  также получить из userAgent. Например

```
  isMSIE6 = ua.indexOf ("msie 6") > -1;//вычисляем любителя ретро (6го ie)
```

(userAgent для различных браузерв можно загуглить - они все есть в открытом доступе и там можно посмотреть какие-либо характерные для конкретного данного браузера строки)

P.S.: замечу, что это - обычный js, а не jQuery (м.б. на jQuery тоже как-то можно - не знаю, но это - в любом случае будет работать)